# using threading and mutex locks to search directories

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, locks

I am new to threading and I believe I understand the concept.  As locks are a necessary tool to use threading but are (or at least to me) confusing on how to use I need to use them but cannot seem to get them correct.  The idea here is to search through directories to find CSV files. (more work will be done on CSVs but that is not relevant here) I have an algorithm to search through directories that works fine without the use of threading.  (keep in mind that searching through directories is the kind of task that is perfect for recursion because you need to search through a directory to find another directory and when you find the new directory you want to search that directory) Since I need to use threading on each instance of finding new directory I have the same algorithm set up twice.  Once in main where it finds directories and the calls a function (through threading) to search the found directories.  Again, if I use this method without threading I have zero problems but with threading the arguments I send in to the function are overwritten.  This happens even if I lock the entire function.  Clearly I am not using locks and threading correctly but where I'm going wrong eludes me.  I have test directories to verify that it is (or is not) working. I have 3 directories in the "." directory and then sub directories beyond that.  It finds the first three directories (in main) fine then when it passes those into the threaded function it will search three different times but usually with searching the same directory more than once.  In other words the path name seems to be overwritten.  I'll post code so you can see what I'm doing.  I thank you in advance. Links to complete code:sorter.h https://pastebin.com/0vQZbrmh sorter.c https://pastebin.com/9wd8aa74 dirWorker.c https://pastebin.com/Jd4i1ecr

In sorter.h

```
#define MAXTHREAD 255
extern pthread_mutex_t lock;
typedef
struct _dir_proc
{
     char* path;        //the path to the new found directory
     char* colName;     //related to the other work that must be done
} dir_proc;
```

In sorter.c

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "sorter.h"

pthread_mutex_t lock;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
      int err = 0;
      pthread_t threads[MAXTHREAD];
      DIR *dirPointer;
      char* searchedDirectory = ".";
      struct dirent *directEntry;
      dir_proc *dir_proc_args = malloc(sizeof(struct _dir_proc));
      assert(dir_proc_args != NULL);
      dir_proc_args->path = (char*) malloc(256 * (sizeof(char));
      assert(dir_proc_args->path != NULL);
      dir_proc_args->colName = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
      assert(dir_proc_args->colName != NULL);
      pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL)

      //dir_proc_args->colName is saved here
      if(!(dirPointer = opendir(searchedDirectory)))
      {
           fprintf(stderr, "opening of directory has failed");
           exit(1);
      }

      while((directEntry = readdir(dirPointer)) != NULL)
      {
           //do stuff here to ensure it is a directory
           //ensure that the dir we are looking at is not current or parent dir
           //copy path of found directory to dir_proc_args->path
           err = pthread_create(&threads[count++], NULL, &CSVFinder, (void*)dir_proc_args);
           if(err != 0)
               printf("can't create thread);
      }
      int i;
      for(i=0; i < count; ++i)
      {
              pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
      }
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
}
```

in CSVFinder function

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "sorter.h"
#include <dirent.h>

void *CSVFinder(void *args)
{
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  //I have locked the entire function to see I can get it to work. this makes no sense to actually do
      DIR *dirPointer;
      struct dirent *directEntry;
      dir_proc *funcArgs = (struct _dir_proc*)args;
      char path[255];
      strncpy(path, funcArgs->path, sizeof(path));

      if(!(dirPointer = opendir(funcArgs->path)))
      {
              fprintf(stderr, "opening of directory has failed");
              exit(1);
      }
      while((directEntry = readdir(dirPointer)) != NULL)
      {
           if(directEntry->d_type == DT_DIR)     //if we are looking at a directory
           {
                  //make sure the dir we are looking at is not current or parent dir
                  snprintf(funcArgs->path, (sizeof(path) + sizeof(directEntry->d_name)), "%s/%s", path, directEntry->d_name);
                 //I would like to be able to do a recursive call here
                 //to search for more directories but one thing at a time
           }
       }
      closedir(dirPointer);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
      return(NULL);
}
```

I hope I have not left out any relevant code.  I tried to keep the code to a minimum while not leaving anything necessary out.

Comment: 'since I need to use threading on each instance of finding new directory' - no, don't do that.  It will not be effective, (in fact, counter-productive).  Do the I/O-bound directory/file scan with one thread and, if a CPU-intensive task, (eg. zipping), needs to be done on each file, queue the file specs, (in some suitable struct), to a pool of threads.

Comment: Ahhh but you're not getting me here.  I'm required to to this.  I completely agree with what you're saying.  I would never do it this way in real life but this is the assignment and I'm required to do it this way.  It makes no sense.

Comment: Well, mallocating the 'dir_proc *dir_proc_args' and loading it up is just fine..except that you only do it once and then use the same dir_proc_args instance for each thread.  That is not going to end well.  malloc a separate instance for each thread else 'the arguments you send in to the function will be overwritten'.

Comment: where's `count` declared/intialized? You're also missing a closing `"` for one of your `printf`s. It's most helpful to post the code you're actually running with,, copy-and-paste is preferable if possible.

Comment: @MartinJames This may be the solution to the problem.  I moved the malloc inside the loop and it seems to be working.  I am going to continue testing and expanding.  I actually had it written like this originally but the code was giving me a problem and I thought having the malloc inside the loop was giving me a problem so I moved it.  I can't thank you enough.  I have to admit I am confused as to why this would fix the problem.  I am changing the content of the structure with each pass through of the loop.

Comment: I have done as you requested.  See original post.

Comment: Re, "the kind of task that is perfect for recursion."   The "kind of task" you have presented is called a  [_tree walk_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), and while a recursive function is an elegant way to implement a _depth first_ tree walk, it's only elegant in a single thread.  Before you try to implement a multi-thread tree walk, you should first learn how to implement one without recursion.  (You will need an explicit stack or queue.)  Once you know how to do it in one thread without recursion, the multi-threaded technique will be a simple extension of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you want to create a thread to simply traverse a directory structure.  However, I will point out a few issues I see.

One minor issue is you in the CSVFinder function, you call readder, not readdir.

But one glaring issue to me is that you do not initialize dirPointer in main or in the CSVFinder() function.  I would expect to see a call like

dirPointer = opendir("/");

in the main() function before the while loop.

Then I would expect to see CSVFinder() initialize its dirPointer with a call to opendir(path) where path is a name to a subdirectory found in the main loop.

For a good reference to how to traverse a directory structure go here...

https://www.lemoda.net/c/recursive-directory/

Comment: Again, there is no problem with searching the directory tree.  When not using threading it works perfectly.  The readder was a type which I have now corrected.  I have also updated the code to show where dirPointer is initialized.  I was attempting to keep the code to a minimum in order to not having you read a lot of irrelevant code.  I apologize for the oversight and would be happy to update the original post with any other information you feel is necessary.

Comment: How about the dirPointer in the CSVFinder() routine?  Is that one initialized with opendir()?

Comment: I have been instructed in the following way "upon finding a directory start a new thread to search that directory".  Not my decision.

Comment: @demist.  The best I can tell you is that the algorithm to search the directory has been proven to work.  It has worked (without threading) hundreds of times and perfectly each time.  Now it may be the case that it is not possible to use that algorithm with threading but without threading it works fine.

Comment: It certainly can work with threading.  Please let me know if you are initializing dirPointer in CSVFinder()?  If you are not, that is clearly an issue.  dirPointer in CSVFinder is a different instance of  dirPointer that is in main.

Comment: I initialize dirPointer in CSVFinder in a similar fashion to how it is done in main.  Except I use funcArgs->path.  I have updated the original post.  Thank you.

Comment: moving the malloc inside the while loop is certainly necessary.  Otherwise every instance of the CSVFinder would be reading that same string.  The thing to note is that each thread may not start immediately after it is created.  All three threads could actually get created before any of them run. If the would happen, than all three threads would have the same path unless unless you created separate memory to store the path for each one of them.

Comment: I also noticed you commented out the lock variable on line 42. Was this intended?

Comment: It was.  I was trying a lot of different things.  This problem has actually been resolved.  The solution offered by @MartinJames above is what fixed it.  Thank you for all the help dernst.